# APEX 19.2 page process & session state

Tags: email, session-state, oracle-apex-19.2

Have a Dynamic Action on an APEX 19.2 form page, which sends an email immediately upon clicking the 'Create' button (done through a DB Package). This email includes data found in the session state. But missing is any value entered on the form page, specifically what is selected in a radio group. Was thinking maybe the radio group item selected can be saved to the session state - then can be included in the email. Wondering how/if this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!! DA's have a "Page Items to Submit" - so needed to include the missing page item to the plsql code. Then alter the DB package specifications & body to process that.